Did MS-DOS cache the FAT?
In the recent discussion about defragmentation utilities, one question that came up was if MS-DOS buffered the FAT sectors, and if yes, to what extent.

From my own DIY operating system based on a FAT, I feel an urgent necessity to cache. My system did not cache, and most file accesses took seconds.

@thebusybee: It's necessary to keep certain information; that doesn't imply keeping the entire FAT cached.  For example, a memory-constrained system which only needs to have one file open at a time fore sequential read-only access might keep a buffer with the locations of up to 16 upcoming clusters.  Any time it needs to find a cluster beyond what it knows, it would read a FAT sector, and the find up to 16 upcoming sectors, or as many sector locations as are specified within the same FAT block as the last sector.  Doing that would improve performance from having to do one FAT sector read...

...for every data sector, to typically having to do only slightly more than one per every 16 data reads--almost doubling perormance in exchange for 33 bytes of RAM.

DOS Plus isn't MS-DOS and so is outside the scope of this question, but I thought it worth noting that it does cache the FAT in memory. Fine on drives of the DOS 2.x/3.x era, but starts to chew up RAM for a filesystem with the full 2^16 clusters.

Fortunately, we now have the source code available for DOS versions 1, 2 and 4. [1]
IBM DOS 1.25 (1982)
(One year after the IBM PC was introduced).
As one can see in MSDOS.ASM, the comment on FATREAD says:

If disk may have been changed, FAT is read in and buffers are
flagged invalid. If not, no action is taken.

So the FAT was always cached, and read in again on disk change.
There is a single sector buffer.
IBM DOS 2.0 (1983)
(Same year as the IBM PC/XT).
The source code already has provisions for a harddisk (HRDDRV.ASM resp. HRDDRV.SYS). There is a generic buffer management in BUF.ASM, and while FAT buffers have special fields (BUFWRTCNT, BUFWRTINC) to deal with multiple FAT copies, the FAT is otherwise managed like a normal sector.
Maybe the hope was that the corresponding FAT sectors would be accessed frequently enough to keep the right FAT sectors in memory most of the time, but with larger harddisks, extremely fragmented files could lead to "FAT thrashing", i.e. necessary reads of FAT sectors.
Tim Paterson had the following to say about this topic [2]:

The new MS-DOS does not keep the file allocation tables in memory at all times. Instead, the tables share the use of the sector buffers along with partial-data transfers. This means that at any one time, all, part, or none of a FAT may be in memory. The buffer-handling algorithms will presumably keep often-used sectors in memory, and this applies to individual sectors of the FAT as well. This change in the DOS goes completely against my original design principles. Memory is getting cheaper all the time, so dedicating a few thousand bytes to the FATs should be completely painless. Now we're back to doing disk reads just to find out where the data is. In the case of a random access to a large fragmented file (for example, when accessing a database that fills half of a small Winchester disk), it is possible that several sectors of the FAT would need to be visited, in random order, to find the needed allocation unit.

As the code for buffering already made a distinction between FAT and non-FAT sectors, it would have been extremely easy to introduce  two sets of buffers, one for FAT sectors, and one for non-FAT sectors, and have both pool sizes been configurable independently, but for some reason this was not done.
IBM DOS 4.0 (1988)
This DOS version introduced partition sizes larger than 32MB. Buffers are now hashed, and can be stored in EMS. Buffers have gained a flag byte, with bits for FAT sectors/directory sectors/plain data. However, one can still see most of the original routines from DOS 2.0 in place.
On the other hand, it now had an extension called FASTOPEN [3]:

FASTOPEN was a very specialized disk cache. FASTOPEN only cached file searches and file opens, and was much more efficient than disk buffers. When a typical application searched for a file (such as PATH searches), it needed to read directory sectors and FAT sectors which contained largely irrelevant information. In a typical case with a relatively small number of disk buffers (10 or so), disk searches had a tendency to force out all useful file buffers and replace them with relatively unimportant directory/FAT buffers, causing increased disk I/O. This was an issue especially with larger disks (in the 100MB+ range). FASTOPEN needed much less memory to cache the same information and thus increased the efficiency of disk buffers.
Additionally, in DOS 4.0 FASTOPEN also implemented so-called FASTSEEK functionality. This was yet another specialized cache for fast access file extent information. As files became large and fragmented, locating various portions of a file required a potentially significant number of disk accesses to read and process the FAT, with expensive seeks moving between the FAT (at the beginning of a disk) and the data area

Summary
Caching of the FAT information was always implemented, but starting with 2.0, it became inefficient for large partitions (and very fragmented files). This was corrected in 4.0.

Sources used:

[1] https://github.com/microsoft/MS-DOS
[2] https://www.lo-tech.co.uk/wiki/An_Inside_Look_at_MS-DOS
[3] https://www.os2museum.com/wp/dos/dos-4-0/


Until DOS 3.0, the number of clusters on a volume was limited to 4095, and the FAT for a volume with 2048 to 4095 clusters would take 3K to 6K of RAM to hold in its entirety.  Even on a system with 192K and one 10MB hard drive (specs which match the first IBM PC upon which I did any programming), spending 4K of RAM keeping a copy of the FAT in memory at all times may not have been the best use of resources.  It would probably have been useful to have the system's buffering logic prioritize FAT sectors ahead of any data sectors that didn't contain the next data that would be read by a currently-open file, but in most scenarios any portion of the FAT that would be useful would be kept in memory by the least-recently-used algorithm, at least if the system kept track of a "there are no free clusters below #XX" to avoid having to reread all of the low-numbered FAT entries when allocated disk space; my recollection is that the system did something like that, though I don't recall any particulars.

"spending 4K of RAM keeping a copy of the FAT in memory at all times" 1. You earlier stated "6K" per FAT, matching the nearly 6 KiB that may actually be needed. 2. The 6 KiB number is per drive, and systems with a hard disk must have supported at least 3 drives so that's 18 KiB for 3 drives' FATs.

@ecm: A drive with 4096 clusters would require keeping 6K of FAT.  A 10MB drive drive would have about 2,500 clusters, requiring between 3.5K and 4K worth of FAT entries, i.e. 8 sectors of 512 bytes each.

When I went on site to repair DOS PCs, half of the time, it meant plugging it in, switching it on, or turning up the brightness.
But no matter what else I did, I always increased the config.sys buffers. It RADICALLY improved things like spell checking, where you couldn't keep the whole dictionary in memory, but you could keep the whole FAT resident to run the cluster chain when searching for words.
It's great when your super power (understanding stuff) can help someone so much — make their work faster and their job easier and their life better.
Like, I noticed that the data entry terminals were running at 1200 baud. In Unix, you can reconfigure the serial ports while the system is running, and one by one I made the data entry people giggle with joy. The majority of their time had been sitting idle waiting for the screen to refresh. Boss liked it too.

The BUFFERS= setting isn't really only providing cache for the FAT, but instead for any disk operation. If other sectors on the disk might be more frequently visited, it might even be there's no part of the FAT cached at all. So, this technically doesn't quite answer the question.

Yes, but if you're looking up words in a spell check dictionary, the FAT would be used continuously and would stay resident. Most PC's never used all of their memory. anyway.  Using some of it to increase disk buffers radically speeded up disk operations.

oh dear, most pc applications under dos struggled to get enough memory

Sometimes, but I mainly worked with secretaries doing word processing, and word processors swap themselves out right to the skeleton so they can run in the least amount of memory.

What editor did you use to edit config.sys? Maybe edlin, dos4 edit or qedit?

config.sys? It's ASCII. Who cares?

SMARTDRV (SmartDrive) in the Autoexec.Bat was one way to provide disk caching in memory. I believe you needed HIMEM in the Config.Sys.

Yeah, but you'd have to copy the whole file into the ram drive.

@MissUnderstands are you mixing up SMARTDRV and RAMDRIVE.SYS? SmartDrive doesn’t provide a RAM drive, it’s a disk cache.

They were different. One was a cache, the other was a temp (RAM) volume.
